# SIGSEGVпри использовании QVector

Tags: c++, qt

Никак не могу понять. Я создал класс с QVector внутри который принимает другой класс, и метод с помощью которого можно в него добавить этот класс. А вот и проблема : Каждый раз когда я использую этот метод меня выкидывает, мол программа не отвечает. Дебаггер говорит что это SIGSEGV и пересылает меня на эту строчку

```
void QVector<T>::append(const T &t)
{
const bool isTooSmall = uint(d->size + 1) > d->alloc; //Вот эта строчка
```

...

Comment: А можно увидеть код в котором используется вектор?

Comment: думаю, там в бесконечном (или достаточно бесконечном) цикле добавляются элементы. И их реально много добавляется.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb
void Worker::add_Ressource(Ressource &l){  
    ressource.push_back(l);  
}

Comment: И что нужно делать, @KoVadim?

Comment: @AstemirTsechoev, я думаю что KoVadim намекает на то, что заканчивается память. Можно весь код глянуть? Ну или минимальный пример на котором воспроизводится ошибка?

Comment: @AstemirTsechoev что делать? фиксить проблему.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb В dialog.cpp я просто использую этот метод и тут выдается ошибка. Просто использую.

Comment: @AstemirTsechoev
Вы похожи на человека, принесшего в автосервис колесо, чтобы ему починили двигатель в машине.
Древнее правило форумов - телепатов не бывает. Хотите помощи, приучайтесь детально описывать свою проблему, прежде всего.
Если много кода, сейчас 21 век, есть пастбин и прочая.

Answer (score 3):

**Ошибки работы с памятью проявляются не там, где была допущена ошибка в коде.** Поэтому не обязательно, что раз дебаггер отправил вас на эту строчку, то ошибка именно в ней. Кроме того, это не ваш код, а код библиотеки Qt, а все библиотеки нужно считать безгрешными, пока не доказано обратное. А добавлять в вектор элементы любого класса можно следующим образом.

```
class SomeClass : public QObject
{
    explicit SomeClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);
}

...

QVector<SomeClass> vector;
SomeClass a, b, c;
vector.append(a);
vector.append(b);
vector.append(c);
```

Comment: Я пробовал сделать вектор публичным, та же проблема выявлялась. Использовал append, но все тщетно. В dialog.cpp (это главное окно). У меня имеется объект класса, который я передаю через параметры метода другого объекта другого класса чтобы он вместил все данные в вектор.

Comment: я работал через push_back и всё хорошо работало

Comment: @AstemirTsechoev, публичность не влияет на ошибки памяти. Ошибки памяти связаны с тем, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к объекту класса, который удалили либо ещё не создали. Приведённый вами код не имеет никакого отношения к проблеме.